Why is SYSOUT=* in master scheduler JCL valid if JES2 has not started yet?
In the MSI phase of the IPL, the master scheduler is loaded into the first address space.  The master scheduler processing is controlled by JCL, and is usually found in the parmlib member MSTJCLXX.  This JCL has statements that use SYSOUT like //SYSLOG DD SYSOUT=*.  But how can SYSOUT be valid when JES2 has not started yet?
